# for loop numbers to be hidden pagination

Tags: php, for-loop

so i have this loop like this

```
 <?php for($i = 0; $i <$size; $i++) { ?>
   <li>
     <a pagenumber="<?php $i+1?>" class="pagination" href="#"><?php $i+1?></a></li>
 <?php } ?>
```

so it kinda looks like this:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

but the problem here is when there is like say a 100 page there is alot of numbers how can i do somthing like this

```
1 2 3 4 5 .... 98 99 100
```

and not have numbers from 1 to 100 just keep showing up
so for example when i click 5 then it should show 
`6 7 8 9...98 99 100`
or somthing better i am not able to figure how to go about this

Comment: Please don't use unrelated tags.  If you don't have jquery or javascript in your code, it's likely you don't want to tag them.

Comment: If I click on 5, I would at least 4 to be visible also.

Comment: ^ agreed Could do `first/prev/ 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20/next/last` say if you were on 15. There are [a lot](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/11/pagination-gallery-examples-and-good-practices/) of ways to go about it. Find an example of exactly what you want? Not really an answer but maybe [look on github](https://github.com/zendframework/zend-paginator/tree/master/src) at how some frameworks handle pagination? Or just do infinite scroll with column sorting since that's how people actually consume "big" tables of data.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to loop.
You can use array_slice and implode to get the expected output.

I added $n to give you the option to output one page previous to the selected if it's not page 1 that is selected.

```
$pages = range(1,100); // range(1, $size);
$page = 1; // page selected by user
if($page ==1){
    $n = 0;
}else{
    $n = 1;
}

echo implode(" ", array_slice($pages, $page-1-$n, 5)) . " . . . . " . Implode(" ", array_slice($pages, -3));
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 . . . . 98 99 100
```

With page 5 selected:

```
4 5 6 7 8 . . . . 98 99 100
```

https://3v4l.org/doZbI

---

If you want to stay in the loop then you can use two loops and one optional echo.

```
$size =100;
$page = 5;

// Echo one page prior to selected page
if($page != 1){
    Echo '<a pagenumber="' . ($page-1) .'" class="pagination" href="#">' . ($page-1) . '</a></li>';
    Echo ' . '; // show dot for current page
}

// Echo +1 -> +5 
For($i = $page+1; $i < $page+6; $i++){
    Echo '<a pagenumber="' . $i .'" class="pagination" href="#">' . $i . '</a></li> ';
}
Echo '. . . . ';

// Echo last three pages
For($i = $size-3; $i <= $size; $i++){
    Echo '<a pagenumber="' . $i .'" class="pagination" href="#">' . $i . '</a></li> ';
}
```

https://3v4l.org/1P0W3

Comment: Minor optimization: `$n = ($page == 1) ? 0 : 1;` Saves 4 lines of code and easily readable.

Comment: I don't like ternarys just because they are harder to read. But that is a preference thing. I doubt it makes the code any faster thus it's only to the eye of the beholder

Comment: It makes it a tad faster because PHP has less text to lex, but its next to negligible. I dislike tanary, but short statements like that well, i'm not gonna nit pic on that. But as you said; preference.

Comment: If it was used in a loop then I would consider it, but since it's a once statement I try to make them as clear as possible.